# Problems with session data permissions, multiple UIDs on multiple PHP-FPM pools

Tags: php, permissions, php-fpm, php.ini, session

I run an nginx server with 40 identical webapps on 40 different ports in 40 different PHP-FPM pools. Each pool is run on a separate user.

My `sessions.save_path` in `php.ini` is `/tmp/php_sessions`. Let's say I first visit `http://mywebsite.com:5007`. I can observe this file pop up in `/tmp/php_sessions`:

```
-rw------- 1 www-data07 www-data07     0 jan.  17 00:35 sess_bb84gmtago2u33g1jmtbhdcu80
```

Then I visit `http://mywebsite.com:5008`. In my browser, I can read this error

```
Warning: Unknown: open(/tmp/php_sessions/sess_bb84gmtago2u33g1jmtbhdcu80, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp/php_sessions) in Unknown on line 0
```

I get that this is because the user `www-data08` is trying to write to a file where only `www-data07` has write permissions. But why doesn't `www-data08` make it's own session data? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I was slightly fast on the trigger here. In my particular instance, the problem was that all 40 webapps shared the same cookie in my browser. When I moved from port 5007 to port 5008, my browser was trying to continue my session from port 5007, but with a different backend UID.